# Google Cloud DNS explanation

Tags: reverse-dns, dns-record

I tried using Google Public DNS to Resolve DNS Records where I tried 36032b.cc.. Below is the result but can somebody explain to me the results? I can not find in the internet any guide on these results.. What does Status:0 means? What is TC, RD, RA, AD. Why do I have multiple answers?

```
{
  "Status": 0,
  "TC": false,
  "RD": true,
  "RA": true,
  "AD": false,
  "CD": false,
  "Question": [
    {
      "name": "36032b.cc.",
      "type": 1
    }
  ],
  "Answer": [
    {
      "name": "36032b.cc.",
      "type": 5,
      "TTL": 299,
      "data": "982020.ssl-cdnweb.net."
    },
    {
      "name": "982020.ssl-cdnweb.net.",
      "type": 1,
      "TTL": 299,
      "data": "18.140.5.212"
    },
    {
      "name": "982020.ssl-cdnweb.net.",
      "type": 1,
      "TTL": 299,
      "data": "139.99.120.10"
    }
  ],
  "Additional": [],
  "Comment": "Response from 159.138.76.159."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue at hand here is a combination of the JSON data just showing the raw values of identifiers in some cases, not the more human and search-friendly names corresponding to these values, but also understanding DNS in general.

For reference regarding the raw values, such as "status 0", etc, I would recommend consulting the [IANA registry for DNS parameters](https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xhtml).

If you look at the *DNS RCODEs* section there, you can see that "status 0" is `NOERROR`, in the *Resource Record (RR) TYPEs* section you can see that "type 5" is `CNAME` and "type 1" is `A`, and in the *DNS Header Flags* section you can see the flags `TC` (Truncated) , `RD` (Recursion Desired) , `RA` (Recursion Available), `AD` (Authentic Data).

Regarding why you have multiple records in the answer:
In your `36032b.cc A` query, the name you looked up (`36032b.cc`) turned out to be an alias (had a `CNAME` record), and the canonical name (`982020.ssl-cdnweb.net`) had two `A` records. Hence three records in the answer.

To just quickly get more readable and search-friendly results you could use for example `dig` which pretty-prints the full response (including the names of things such as known status codes and types):

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.28-RedHat-9.11.28-1.fc33 <<>> 36032b.cc
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6182
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;36032b.cc.                     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
36032b.cc.              299     IN      CNAME   982020.ssl-cdnweb.net.
982020.ssl-cdnweb.net.  300     IN      A       139.99.120.10
982020.ssl-cdnweb.net.  300     IN      A       18.140.5.212

;; Query time: 1202 msec
;; SERVER: 139.162.131.5#53(139.162.131.5)
;; WHEN: Sun Mar 28 14:00:11 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 105
```